# IFilter is not run by Windows indexing service

Tags: com, ifilter

OS: Win 8.1, x86

I am trying to develop an IFilter for a proprietary file format.  The IPersistStream interface is implemented in the filter (although there is no tool to test this interface...). The DLL goes through all the tests in the IFilter test suite (ifilttst, filtdump, filtreg; ifilttst emitted property/values are correct), it is installed in c:\windows\system32 but it is not properly run by SearchFilterHost.exe used by Windows indexing services. Nothing is indexed.

I used Process Monitor (procmon.exe) to look at when SearchFilterHost is using the IFilter. During re-indexing of the disk or when a file name handled by the IFilter is changed, SearchFilterHost loads the image of the IFilter, but then nothing else happens.

Dependency Walker found DLLs that were missing (some are found in the c:\windows\system32) (IEHIMS.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORExxx.DLL etc...) but I doubt (I could be wrong) it would make much of a difference because the ifilttst is running fine.

I am at my wit's end. Could someone help?

Thanks

Comment: is your filter 32 bit or 64 bit? What about your OS?

Comment: Your best bet is to add logging to each of your method and also to `QueryInterface()` so that you know which interfaces are being requested (and whether you can supply those) and which methods are invoked with what parameters (and whether your code handles this properly).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? If so, please post it as an answer.